# Setting a global, custom validator for Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I can set a custom `org.springframework.validation.Validator` in a controller's `@InitBinder`.

But how do I set a validator that will be used whenever the default validator is processing a specific class, including its nested properties?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `@ControllerAdvice` component with `@InitBinder` method. Be sure to use `addValidators` method instead of `setValidator` in all `@InitBinder` methods.

As for nested properties. This is done by annotating a nested field in class with `@Valid` annotation.

Comment: Moved the `@InitBinder` method to a `@ControllerAdvice` class. However, even when using `addValidators`, the custom validator is called for any class. If I return `false` from the `supports` method for other classes, validation of those classes fails. So my current workaround is to wrap the "default" validator inside the custom validator, and delegate calls for validating objects I don't want to validate myself to that...

Comment: @ejain The behavior of `supports` method you described sounds weird. Could you show your Validator class and an example of how you invoke validation?

Comment: I'm relying on Spring to invoke validation on controller method arguments annotated with `javax.validation.Valid`, e.g. `public void post(@Valid @RequestBody Person p)`. My original validator implementation looks pretty much like the `PersonValidator` example in the docs at http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html.